# How to get event touch move of UIView when move finger from outside view

Tags: ios

I have a UIView custom. In this UIView custom, I have a small UIImageView. When I move finger through it, it will move with my finger. To do that, I use UIPanGestureRecognizer (add this gesture to UIImageView). But when I move finger with begining point not in UIImageView, it will not handle this event.
So, my question is "How to get event touch move of UIView when move finger from outside view ?"
Thanks.

Comment: You have to get the touch move on the outside view and check if the touch coordinates are over the UIImageView

Comment: Thank you. I think that is a good answer and final answer. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach is create a uiview with necessary size(which is larger than uiimageview). Place the uiimageview inside it. Add gesture recognizer to uiview instead of uiimageview. In the delegate method of geature, move the image view.

Comment: Thank you. Is your answer mean like @jcesar comment ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Touch Drag Enter" Event which might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is not working. I checked, and know that all event have to begin inside UIView first.